# canvas drawing with on click

Tags: javascript, canvas

On my game click on the HUD button top left. Then mess around with the sub-menus.
I want it so when yo click a subment it opens that meny and the button slides out. All this is working but sometimes it takes an extra click. I do not know if this is because of canvas or my method?
Test it here: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html

here is the code:

```
function drawHUD(num) {
    ctxHUD.globalAlpha = 0.85;

    if(num == 0) {

        var srcX = 165;
        var srcY = 605;
        var drawX = 580;
        var drawY = 180;
        var HUDWidth = 400;
        var HUDHeight = 400;

        ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

        var srcX = 25;
        var srcY = 600;
        var drawX = 448;
        var drawY = 180;
        var HUDWidth = 135;
        var HUDHeight = 335;

        ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);
    } else if(num == 1) {

        if(HUD1Flag == false) {

            drawHUD(0);
            HUD1Flag = true;
        } else {




            var srcX = 165;
            var srcY = 605;
            var drawX = 580;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 400;
            var HUDHeight = 400;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ///////////////////////////
            var srcX = 25;
            var srcY = 670;
            var drawX = 448;
            var drawY = 250;
            var HUDWidth = 135;
            var HUDHeight = 270;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ////////////////////////////////////
            var srcX = 0;
            var srcY = 940;
            var drawX = 421;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 170;
            var HUDHeight = 75;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);
            HUD1Flag = false;
        }

    } else if(num == 2) {

        if(HUD2Flag == false) {

            drawHUD(0);
            HUD2Flag = true;
        } else {




            var srcX = 165;
            var srcY = 605;
            var drawX = 580;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 400;
            var HUDHeight = 400;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ///////////////////////////
            var srcX = 25;
            var srcY = 600;
            var drawX = 448;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 135;
            var HUDHeight = 335;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ////////////////////////////////////
            ctxHUD.clearRect(447, 251, 137, 65);
            /////////////////////////////
            var srcX = 0;
            var srcY = 1013;
            var drawX = 423;
            var drawY = 249;
            var HUDWidth = 170;
            var HUDHeight = 75;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);
            HUD2Flag = false;

        }

    } else if(num == 3) {

        if(HUD3Flag == false) {

            drawHUD(0);
            HUD3Flag = true;
        } else {




            var srcX = 165;
            var srcY = 605;
            var drawX = 580;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 400;
            var HUDHeight = 400;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ///////////////////////////
            var srcX = 25;
            var srcY = 600;
            var drawX = 448;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 135;
            var HUDHeight = 335;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ////////////////////////////////////
            ctxHUD.clearRect(447, 320, 137, 65);
            /////////////////////////////
            var srcX = 0;
            var srcY = 1088;
            var drawX = 423;
            var drawY = 320;
            var HUDWidth = 170;
            var HUDHeight = 73;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);
            HUD3Flag = false;

        }

    } else if(num == 4) {

        if(HUD4Flag == false) {

            drawHUD(0);
            HUD4Flag = true;
        } else {




            var srcX = 165;
            var srcY = 605;
            var drawX = 580;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 400;
            var HUDHeight = 400;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);
            ///////////////////////////

            ctxHUD.globalAlpha = 0.7;
            ctxHUD.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
            ctxHUD.font = '10px Verdana Bold';


            ctxHUD.fillText('Dark Orbit is a highly illegal starship arena created by', 613, 207);
            ctxHUD.fillText('Argok Stall, a founding member of the black market and', 613, 220);
            ctxHUD.fillText('undefeated starship fighter.', 613, 233);


            ctxHUD.fillText('Welcome to Dark Orbit - Currently in development', 613, 543);
            ctxHUD.fillText('Design/Programming - Wayne Daly', 613, 556);


            ///////////////////////////
            var srcX = 25;
            var srcY = 600;
            var drawX = 448;
            var drawY = 180;
            var HUDWidth = 135;
            var HUDHeight = 335;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);

            ////////////////////////////////////
            ctxHUD.clearRect(447, 386, 137, 65);
            /////////////////////////////
            var srcX = 0;
            var srcY = 1160;
            var drawX = 423;
            var drawY = 387;
            var HUDWidth = 170;
            var HUDHeight = 73;

            ctxHUD.drawImage(spriteImage, srcX, srcY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight, drawX, drawY, HUDWidth, HUDHeight);
            HUD4Flag = false;

        }

    }


}
```

Mouse cliked method:

```
function HUDClicked(e)
{

mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);



 if (mouseX > 910 && mouseX < 990)
 {


  if (mouseY > 10 && mouseY< 41)

 {


   if(HUDFlag == false)
       {
           drawHUD(0);
           HUDFlag = true;

       }
      else
     {
       ClearHUD();
        HUDFlag = false;

     }        

 }  
 }


 if (mouseX > 450 && mouseX < 582)
 {


 if (mouseY > 185 && mouseY< 244)

 {


   if(HUDFlag == false)
       {


       }
      else
     {
       ClearHUD();
       drawHUD(1);
     }        

 }  
 }

  if (mouseX > 450 && mouseX < 582)
 {


 if (mouseY > 252 && mouseY< 315)

 {


   if(HUDFlag == false)
       {


       }
      else
     {
       ClearHUD();
       drawHUD(2);
     }        

 }  
 }

 if (mouseX > 450 && mouseX < 582)
 {


 if (mouseY > 320 && mouseY< 382)

 {


   if(HUDFlag == false)
       {


       }
      else
     {
       ClearHUD();
       drawHUD(3);
     }        

 }  
 }

  if (mouseX > 450 && mouseX < 582)
   {


  if (mouseY > 388 && mouseY< 450)

 {


   if(HUDFlag == false)
       {


       }
      else
     {
       ClearHUD();
       drawHUD(4);
     }        

 }  
 }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the variables such as HUD4Flag with the meanings:

1. false means icon 4 is sticking out
2. true means icon 4 is in its default position

This means that if you click on an icon and it is sticking out (false), you draw everything as normal and icon 4 goes back to its default position (true).

With this interpretation you should make sure that when you set HUD4Flag false, all the rest of the flags should be set true.  However, this is not done at the moment and you can end up with more than one flag false at the same time.

The problem at the moment is that when you click on 1, then 2, you will end up with both HUD1Flag=false and HUD2Flag=false.  If you then click on 1 again nothing appears to happen.  In fact you are changing HUD1Flag to true, and a second click will make the icon appear.

One way to fix this is to change the lines such as

```
HUD3Flag = false;
```

to also clear the other flags

```
HUD1Flag = true;
HUD2Flag = true;
HUD3Flag = false;
HUD4Flag = true;
```